# WKWebView intermittent blank screen issue

Tags: ios, ios8, wkwebview

I'm integrating WKWebView to our App. And see various issues. The most annoying and blocking one is intermittent blank screen. It can be triggered my many things, navigation, zooming, etc.

When I examine the view hierarchy inside WKWebView, I can see lots of subviews are missing. When I hook up a inspector, the HTML is properly loaded. And sometimes, I can see a message in the console log:

```
Received an invalid message "RemoteLayerTreeDrawingAreaProxy.CommitLayerTree" from the web process.
```

We already filed couple of radar to Apple. Does anyone had similar problem and found a walk around?

Answer (score 21):

WKWebView's WebProcess runs out-of-process as a 64-bit process on hardware supporting 64bit.  There is a 32bit/64bit marshalling IPC bug for 32 bit apps using the WKWebView client on such hardware.  The bug causes the WebProcess to exit, leaving a blank screen.

You can verify this by 1) running your app on hardware that only supports 32bit and supports iOS 8 (e.g. iPad 2), or by building a 64bit version of your app.  (Can build a 64 bit only version as a sanity test.)

Comment: Cool first post! `;)`

Comment: Awesome! I had a project that was set to only build 32-bit. Allowing 64-bit fixed a bunch of issues I was having with WKWebView.

Comment: Yup. Apple has confirm there is such bug. And we are indeed building 32bit only. Interestingly, we had some repro on an 4S too, though I don't see the message but same blank screen. It seems that it related to memory stress.

Comment: Did the bug get fixed in 8.1?

Comment: It is not fixed in 8.1. I too need to build 32bit as I have inlude a 3rd party lib which only runs in 32bit.  So what I need to do is create 2 apps:  one for iPad2 (32bit) which can use wkWebView and one for iPad Air (64bit) which uses uiWebView.  ha funny...

Comment: I am still getting this on iOS 10.2 on an iPhone 6. What's been discovered recently? My build retains iPad 2 / iOS 8.0 compatibility and so retains 32 bit compatibility.